# VirtualBox - Bind to specific VLAN/Interface for NAT purposes

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

On my machine I have 4 Vlans on a single interface, and when setting up networks in the GUI of Virtualbox I can see no way to choose which interface it will sit 'behind' when I create a NAT, or tell it to use NAT for a single VM.

[image]

The manual at [Virtual Box NAT Configuration](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat) states I should use `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natbindip1 "10.45.0.2"` to bind it to the correct interface however when i run this command in a prompt it tells me the command is not found.

How do I go about binding this correctly?

Comment: It's not by default added to the path. You will have to navigate to the VirtualBox directory manually.

Comment: @Seth go ahead and answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Oracle doesn't add the path of their tools to the path variable on Windows.

In order to use `VBoxManage` you will have to either add it to your path variable or navigate to the proper directory on the console using `cd`/use the full path.